# Handle Response from nodejs to take action

Tags: node.js

I am a newbie in nodejs, I am trying to make an application where nodejs return an html page and user submit the book name using POST nodejs returns a response with one or matching books
I was able to complete this successfully, but now I want to take some action based on response from nodejs, but I am able to find out how can I do the same, e.g. if response has lot of books, I want to ask user which book you want and once user select the book, i want to send that book id back to find the book details. I dont know how to store and take action on the response
I searched a lot, but failed to find any solution

Comment: add what had you tried too. so we can find out the issue.

Comment: I guess the problem is, I dont know what should I add in my code to handle the response. I am able to get the respone in html or json format and can display on browser, but I dont know what should I add in my code to handle this response so that i can take any action. If i can get a hint or direction what i can try would be very helpful